# Creating a 2D array moves data to key position

Tags: php, arrays

I declare the following array

```
$job_scope = array( "proposal_id",
                    "will_provide" => array("0","Supervision","Labor","Material","Equpment"),          
                    "general_scope",          
                    "per_bid" => array("Yes","No","Omit"),               
                    "job_type"  => array("Painting","Sandblasting","Scappling")
);
```

I expect it to be created like

```
array([0] => 'proposal_id',
      [1] => 'will_provide' => array([0] => "0",
                                     [1] => "Supervision",
                                     [2] => "Labor",
                                     [3] => "Material",
                                     [4] => "Equpment"),
      [2] => 'general_scope',
      [3] => 'per_bid'      => array([0] => "Yes",
                                     [1] => "No",
                                     [2] => "Omit"),

      [4] => 'job_type'     => array([0] => "Painting",
                                     [1] => "Sandblasting",
                                     [2] => "Scappling")
```

But when I print the array it looks like

```
Array ( [0] => proposal_id [will_provide] => Array (
                                                [0] => 0
                                                [1] => Supervision 
                                                [2] => Labor
                                                [3] => Material
                                                [4] => Equpment )

    [1] => general_scope [per_bid] =>    Array ( 
                                               [0] => Yes 
                                               [1] => No 
                                               [2] => Omit )

    [job_type] =>                       Array ( 
                                                [0] => Painting 
                                                [1] => Sandblasting 
                                                [2] => Scappling )
```

I would like the array to be created in the same format as the second section of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is assign an empty array to the `proposal_id` and `general_scope`. So the code will look like this

```
$job_scope = array( "proposal_id" => array(),
                "will_provide" => array("0","Supervision","Labor","Material","Equpment"),          
                "general_scope" => array(),          
                "per_bid" => array("Yes","No","Omit"),               
                "job_type"  => array("Painting","Sandblasting","Scappling")
                );
```

It will produce this array

```
Array ( 
   [proposal_id] => Array ( ) 
   [will_provide] => Array ( [0] => 0 
                             [1] => Supervision 
                             [2] => Labor 
                             [3] => Material 
                             [4] => Equpment 
                           )
   [general_scope] => Array ( ) 
   [per_bid] => Array ( [0] => Yes 
                        [1] => No 
                        [2] => Omit 
                      ) 
   [job_type] => Array ( [0] => Painting 
                         [1] => Sandblasting 
                         [2] => Scappling 
                       ))
```

If you want to callback the value, (ex : call `supervision` value).

All you need to do is

`print_r($job_scope['will_provide'][1])`

and that will print the `supervision` value

Answer (score 1):

use `$new_job_scope = array_values($job_scope);`

```
$job_scope = array( 
    "proposal_id",
    "will_provide" => array(
            "0",
            "Supervision",
            "Labor",
            "Material",
            "Equpment"
    ),          
    "general_scope",          
    "per_bid" => array(
        "Yes",
        "No",
        "Omit"
    ),               
    "job_type"  => array(
        "Painting",
        "Sandblasting",
        "Scappling"
    )
);

$new_job_scope = array_values($job_scope);

print_r($new_job_scope);
```

[PhpFiddle](http://ideone.com/i701gY)

Answer (score 1):

Create array first !!! Reassign at specified index with 2D array will be more clear to me

```
<?php
$arr = array('proposal_id','','general_scope','',''); //create array first
$arr[1] = array("will_provide" => array("0","Supervision","Labor","Material","Equpment"));
$arr[3] = array("per_bid" =>  array("Yes","No", "Omit"));
$arr[4] = array("job_type" => array("Painting","Sandblasting","Scappling"));
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this process can serve you.  I have just used a foreach loop to convert non-int key to int key:

```
$new_array = '';
foreach($job_scope as $k => $v){
    if(is_int($k)){
        $new_array[] = $v;
    }else{
        $new_array[] = [$k => $v];
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => proposal_id
    [1] => Array
        (
            [will_provide] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => Supervision
                    [2] => Labor
                    [3] => Material
                    [4] => Equpment
                )

        )

    [2] => general_scope
    [3] => Array
        (
            [per_bid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Yes
                    [1] => No
                    [2] => Omit
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [job_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Painting
                    [1] => Sandblasting
                    [2] => Scappling
                )

        )

)
```